# Handle all of an array's events

Tags: arrays, vb.net, events

So I have a class which contains a few controls for easy UI design and it has a custom event which is raised whenever the combo box inside the panel is changed:

```
Public Class BatInputLine
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Panel

    Public Event SelectionChanged As EventHandler

    Protected Overridable Sub OnSelectionChanged(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent SelectionChanged(Me, e)
    End Sub

     Private Sub NameSet(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
     Handles_cboName.SelectedIndexChanged

        PlayerName = _playerNames(_cboName.SelectedIndex)
        SelectedIndex = _cboName.SelectedIndex

        OnSelectionChanged(EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

An array of these is declared and the user inputs a number according to how many of these they need on screen on a new Form.

```
ReDim _batInputs(GetNumberOfbatsmen())
```

I want to call a sub procedure whenever the SelectionChanged event is raised by any of the instances of BatInputLine in _batInputs(). If I try to write a handler e.g sub doSometing(sender as Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _batInputs(0).SelectionChanged I get an error saying that that the _batInput elements need to be declared with a WithEvents modifier, but I don't quite know how to do them.

a) How can I declare this array where all of the indexes get the WithEvents Modifier?

b) How can I assign a sub procedure that is called when these events are raised, which is in the new form?

Comment: your question is just not clear enough... with 'An array of these is declared', do you mean an array of BatInputLine classes? Whats; Handle all of an array's events?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is an array of the BaTInputLines, and I want to call a sub procedure whenever the SelectionChanged event is raised by any of the instances of BatInputLine in _batInputs(). If I try to write a handler e.g sub doSometing(sender as Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _batInputs(0).SelectionChanged         I get an error saying that that the _batInput elements need to be declared with a WithEvents modifier, but I don't quite know how to do that for them all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made use of the AddHandler keyword, which I didn't know existed.

```
for i = 0 to _batInputs.Length -1
     AddHandler _batInputs(i).SelectionChanged, AddressOf HandleSelectionChangedEvent
next

Private Sub HandleSelectionChangedEvent
    'do something
End Sub
```